# Link no funciona al estar dentro de dos pseudoclases con content: ''

Tags: html, css

Tengo un div que tiene tanto un before como un after con content: '' para poder animar el borde de este. Pero me encuentro que al poner un link, este no funciona.
Ahi va lo que tengo hecho:

```css
.inner-block {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.inner-block::before, .inner-block::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.inner-block::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-right-color: #000;
  animation: border 2s normal forwards;
}

.inner-block::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: border 2s 1s normal forwards, borderColor 2s 1s normal forwards;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes borderColor {
  0% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
  51% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-block">
  <header>
    <a href="#">Título</a>
  </header>
</div>
```

Supongo que al tener content: '' es lógico, pero no se como puedo solucionarlo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que realmente no estás haciendo click en el link ya que el `after` y el `before` lo "tapan". Una solución sería utilizar el [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

```
.inner-block::before, .inner-block::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona!

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución, es que declares que los "seudos" no van a ser clickqueables, usando `pointer-events: none`. Ej:

```
.inner-block::before, 
.inner-block::after{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```css
.inner-block {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.inner-block::before, .inner-block::after {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;  
  pointer-events: none; /*<-- solo agrega esto*/
}

.inner-block::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-right-color: #000;
  animation: border 2s normal forwards;
}

.inner-block::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: border 2s 1s normal forwards, borderColor 2s 1s normal forwards;
}

@keyframes border {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes borderColor {
  0% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
  50% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
  51% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
  }
}

/*Esto de abajo ignoralo*/

body{display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 80vh;
}.inner-block{padding:1em;}
```

```html
<div class="inner-block">
  <header>
    <a href="#">Título</a>
  </header>
</div>
```